# PHP array cannot be longer

Tags: php, html

In PHP I just declared an array with a lot of elements but after 23 elements I had to create separate statements to push the other elements into the array.  Why did the variable stop being a variable (not highlighting anymore and causing the html that came next not to highlight) when I tried to declare it as an array with more than 23 elements?

```
$params = array( $first_and_last_name, $address, $phone, $email, $affiliation, $affiliation_address, $affiliation_phone, $affiliation_phone, $affiliation_extension, $affiliation_fax, $affiliation_fax, $affiliation_email, $session1_checkbox, $session1_attending, $session2_checkbox, $session2_attending, $admin_survey_checkbox, $street_team_checkbox, $assist_at_event_checkbox, $identify_and_report_checkbox, $post_flyers_checkbox, $donate_checkbox, $donate_amount);

array_push($params, $provide_staff_checkbox, $provide_information_checkbox, $provide_service_checkbox, $service_specify );
```

as you can see I use an `array_push()` to make the array correctly, I am just confused as to why because it will surely impact my future PHP code.

the same thing happens with a longer string that I declare in the same document.  I have to add the strings together rather than write the whole string as one variable:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO phc_registrations (first_and_last_name, address, phone, email, affiliation, affiliation_address, affiliation_phone, affiliation_phone, affiliation_extension, affiliation_fax,";
$sql .= "affiliation_fax, affiliation_email, session1_checkbox, session1_attending, session2_checkbox, session2_attending, admin_survey_checkbox, street_team_checkbox, ";
$sql .= "assist_at_event_checkbox, identify_and_report_checkbox, post_flyers_checkbox, donate_checkbox, donate_amount, provide_staff_checkbox, provide_information_checkbox, provide_service_checkbox, service_specify ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

and by "highlight" I mean syntax highlighting in my IDE (atom).  I know the highlighting is not a function of PHP but I am trying to find out if this issue was a failiure by my IDE (atom) or PHP itself or something else.

Comment: Share some code so people can help you to understand what happen

Comment: because somewhere in your array syntax you missed double quote marks or single, whatever you are using, or may be instead of using COMMA you have used the semi colon. Posting your code can help us both to determine the issue

Comment: Please add your code to the question. And what do you mean by highlight?

Comment: What ide are you using? Highlighting isn’t actually a language construct. It’s an ide feature.

Comment: @BlackXero and the others: ok I added the code and a further explanation.

Comment: @Ben Try to put each variable you are putting in the array on it's own line and see if the syntax highlighting is working. This has a few other added benefits as well, such as making it easier to see what the array contains without scrolling sideways, and helps you eliminate issues with commas.

Comment: oh ok great, and I don't mean to be rude but that doesn't answer my question.  Was the fact that declaring these longer variables in one line breaks the rest of the code a failure if my IDE or of PHP or do I have to set a PHP variable to something larger?

Comment: I would say that it's a failure of your IDE. Have you tried to run the code with the wrong highlighting and was it working or not?

Comment: @Johnny yes the code with the wrong highlighting DOES execute so this is probably not a failiure of PHP, but does that means its either the fault of a) the code highlighting core package in atom, or b) some PHP constant that the code highlighter is referencing (like a buffer size or something) that is too low.  Any ideas?